# iFrame not executing javascript from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe, xss

TL;DR: I have an iframe which makes an AJAX call to a Rails app that returns a Javascript response. After upgrading my app from Rails 2.3 to 5.1, the Javascript is now rendered as text inside the iframe instead of executed. Any idea why?

Full details:

My legacy Rails app renders the following partial as the UI for the user to upload a csv file:

```
<div class="uploadForm" style="">
  <iframe src="/my_controller/upload_file/1" width="320px" height="195px" style="border:none;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

In Rails 2.3 routes of the form `controller#action` were dynamically generated, but this turned out to be a security risk; so in the upgraded version I've had to manually specify a route; I removed the trailing `/1`, as I have no idea what it was doing and it didn't appear to be needed. The action `my_controller#upload_file` simply renders the following partial:

```
<!--stylesheet link/>

<% form_tag( url_for(:controller=>'my_controller', :action => 'csv_import',:previous_window => 'window.opener' ), :multipart => true) do %>
<input id='file_upload' name='file' size='20' type='file' />
<%= submit_tag 'OK' %>
 #radio buttons
<% end %>
```

On submission, the form is processed by the action `my_controller#csv_import`:

```
def csv_import
 #code that handles parsing csv
 render :partial => "return_file"
end
```

In the legacy app, the partial `_return_file.rhtml` (told you it was legacy!) looked like (slightly simplified)

```
<script>
 alert("Successfully processed <%= @added %> rows")
</script>
```

which executed fine. However, trying this same thing in my 5.1 app (renaming the `.rhtml` to `.html.erb`) doesn't work, instead rendering the text (script tags and all) inside my iframe. I tried instead changing it to a `.js.erb` extension, using

```
render :partial => "return_file", formats: :js
```

as I'm using everywhere else I want to return Javascript in the project, but get the same result. I have literally no idea why, and none of the other answers about JS in iFrames seem relevant to this case, so any help would be enormously appreciated.

EDIT: In response to Sikandar Tariq's answer below, I compared the response headers for the old and new versions of my site, and found that the new version added the following headers:

```
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:879d2d21-b1fa-43e8-8e03-6cd5e78ef72f
X-Runtime:0.403123
X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block
```

My guess is that the last term is the one that's causing me grief, and it somehow mistakenly identifies a XSS attack so it displays the response as plain text instead of rendering it. But why would it erroneously flag this when `X-Frame-Options` is set to `SAMEORIGIN`? I mean, I know that iframes are regarded in most contexts as a separate domain, but isn't the `X-Frame-Options` designed specifically for iframes?

EDIT EDIT:
I added the following lines of code to my controller before calling render.

```
response.headers["X-XSS-Protection"] = "0"
response.headers.delete('X-Frame-Options')
```

My problem persists. I've checked that these lines have taken effect in the response.

Answer (score 0):

iframs act as different website/domains, so calling ajax from iframe is like cross-domain execution which is not allowed for the sake of security. See same-origin policy for more information

Comment: Thanks for the reply - is there a reason it worked in the old Rails if this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a way of fixing this. I have *literally no idea* why it works, so any helpful advice or explanations would still be received with gratitude and upvotes.
When the steps outlined in my edits to the post didn't work, I first of all decided to remove all response headers that related to XSS:

```
response.headers.keys.each do |header|
  response.headers.delete(header) if header =~ /X-/
end
```

I decided that this was safe as no user-supplied data is getting passed to the view, just some integers I've calculated based on user supplied data; this may not be a safe option for you.

Then, bizarrely, I had to get rid of rendering the call to render the response as Javascript, and instead render html and wrap my Javascript in`<script>` tags.

Like I said, this is posted in case it helps anyone else, but if anyone has anything to add I'd be grateful.